# Datastax QueryBuilder insert statement

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

What would be the right way to build a insert statement with QueryBuilder from Datastax Java Driver for Cassandra

I am using Cassandra 2.x with Java Driver 2.0.0-rc1

I know i could use a prepared statement to achieve the same but i am looking forward to using the QueryBuilder

```
@Test
public void testTableInsert() {
    Insert insert = QueryBuilder
            .insertInto(KEYSPACE_NAME, TABLE_NAME)
            .value("username", "jdoe")
            .value("first", "John")
            .value("last", "Doe");
    System.out.println(insert.toString());
    ResultSet result = session.execute(insert.toString());
    System.out.println(result);

}
```

I can confirm the query string is valid because it succeeds when attempting manually on cqlsh

```
INSERT INTO test.user(username,first,last) VALUES ('jdoe','John','Doe');
```

The error reported by the driver is

```
    com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigured columnfamily user
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException.copy(InvalidQueryException.java:35)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ResultSetFuture.extractCauseFromExecutionException(ResultSetFuture.java:271)
    at       com.datastax.driver.core.ResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(ResultSetFuture.java:187)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Session.execute(Session.java:126)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Session.execute(Session.java:77)
    at SimpleClientTest.testTableInsert(SimpleClientTest.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:77)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigured columnfamily user
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:96)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ResultSetFuture$ResponseCallback.onSet(ResultSetFuture.java:122)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:224)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.onSet(RequestHandler.java:359)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.messageReceived(Connection.java:510)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneDecoder.handleUpstream(OneToOneDecoder.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:109)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:312)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:90)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

I couldn't find any examples on the official documentation page at [here](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/java-driver/1.0/webhelp/index.html#java-driver/reference/queryBuilder_r.html)

Comment: Just ran your code and it works fine. Check that you haven't actually dropped the "user" CF and make sure that KEYSPACE_NAME is what you expect it to be (i.e. "test")

Comment: @LyubenTodorov thank you for trying this out. You can see my answer as to why i was seeing this error. It boils down to the Session object not refreshing its TableMetaData which is obtained when the Session object is created.

Comment: That sounds odd, can you show me the code you are using (maybe in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/))

Comment: @LyubenTodorov You can just issue the create table query before the query without recreating a session. modified code at https://gist.github.com/adilfulara/8944508

Comment: You aren't creating the keyspace in that query, you are only creating a table. Where is the keyspace created? Does it already exist?

Comment: @LyubenTodorov The keyspace already exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just forgot to create the keyspace.

Full code used to create a KS, create a CF and use the querybuilder to insert a partition.

```
public static void main(String[] Args)
{
    Cluster cluster = null;
    cluster = Cluster.builder()
                     .addContactPoint("127.0.0.1")
                     .build();
    Session session = cluster.connect();

    try
    {
        String createKS = "CREATE KEYSPACE test WITH REPLICATION = { 'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '2' }";
        session.execute(createKS);
        String query = "create table test.user (username text primary key,first text, last text);";
        session.execute(query);

        System.out.println("insert executed");
        Insert insert = QueryBuilder.insertInto("test", "user")
                                    .value("username", "jdoe")
                                    .value("first", "John")
                                    .value("last", "Doe");
        System.out.println(insert.toString());
        ResultSet result = session.execute(insert.toString());
        System.out.println(result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Did this work ? What version of Cassandra did this work against?

Comment: You code works fine. I will have to try to on the home machine later tonight where i did see a problem. This is strange.

Comment: i will accept your answer as it works flawlessly. but i still dont understand why i saw the error.

Comment: @AdilF Your code doesn't create the keyspace (database) that stores the column family (table) Its the first two lines after the try that create the keyspace and solve the problem.

Comment: The reason i don't create a keyspace is because it exists in the cluster.

Answer (score 4):

There is no problem in the code. The error is due to the fact that the CF being queried was created in the same session. In such a case, one needs to create a new Session to the cluster for the Session to get the TableMetaData about the CF. I just assumed that since a connection was established, the Session would update its TableMetaData before a Insert statement. Unfortunately not the case.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem but arrived at a different solution. In my case I had an integration test, running multiple tests against a Cassandra instance; four tests (not using batches) succeeded flawlessly, a fifth (using batches) failed.

For some reason the CQL parser converts all names to lower-case so if you have a keyspace or column family name with mixed case letters you have to surround the name of the keyspace or column family with quotes, i.e.

```
QueryBuilder.insertInto(String.format("\"%s\"", COLUMN_FAMILY)).…
```