# Passing parameters to Cassandra using Scala

Tags: scala, parameters, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver

I want to pass parameters into a query execute connecting to Cassandra in Scala:

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.{Session, Cluster}

val cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("localhost").build()//withPort(8080).build()
val session = cluster.connect("MyKeySpace")
```

Just found this in Python but I want to do it in Scala:

```
session.execute(
  """
  INSERT INTO users (name, credits, user_id)
  VALUES (%s, %s, %s)
  """,
  ("John O'Reilly", 42, uuid.uuid1())
)
```

Comment: I am using IntelliJ to create a jar file and run in spark with spark-submit

Comment: Could clarify what the issue is or what are you trying to achieve? You are connecting to the Cassandra cluster using Scala and you are trying to run the insert? If yes, do you have problems when you run it? or it does not work or you don't know how to do it? Be more descriptive with the issue that you are facing

Answer (score 0):

For passing parameters to a query you can use [String Interpolation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html) in `Scala`.
Suppose you have your query parameters in `name`, `credits` and `userId`, then you can use something like below.

```
val name = "John O'Reilly"
val credits = 42
val userId = java.util.UUID.randomUUID()

session.execute(
  s"""
  INSERT INTO users (name, credits, user_id)
  VALUES ($name, $credits, $userId)
  """
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using plain Scala/Java, I recommend to use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.3/manual/statements/prepared/) instead:

1. It provides better performance if the same statement is executed several times, because you don't need to parse it multiple times, and only data is transferred between client & server;
2. It doesn't require that you do string escaping yourself - in string interpolation case you need to take care that quotes are correctly escaped, etc.

Small example (from documentation):

```
PreparedStatement prepared = session.prepare(
    "insert into product (sku, description) values (?, ?)");

BoundStatement bound = prepared.bind("234827", "Mouse");
session.execute(bound);
```

You can also bind individual parameters by name, unbind some, etc.

Also, if you're accessing Cassandra from Spark, then it would be better to use [Spark-Cassandra-Connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector) that performs a lot of optimization when reading & writing data from/to Cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `QueryBuilder`:

```scala
val keySpaceName = "MyKeySpace"
val tableName = "users"
val insert = QueryBuilder.insertInto(keySpaceName, tableName)
  .value("name", "John O'Reilly")
  .value("credits", "42")
  .value("user_id", java.util.UUID.randomUUID())
val result = session.execute(insert.toString)
```

The solution was adapted from: [Datastax QueryBuilder insert statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21667425/datastax-querybuilder-insert-statement)